# How to create a timetracker?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm very new to Python.
I want to create a script for time tracking with a grafical interface.
Once you hit start the start time should be stored and when you hit stop the time difference shoult be displayed.

This is my approach to the topic:

```
import datetime
from Tkinter import *

root=Tk()

def starttime():
    start=datetime.datetime.now()
    print start

def stoptime():
    stop=datetime.datetime.now()
    print stop
    delta=stop-start
    print delta

startb = Button(root, text="Start", command=starttime)
startb.pack()
stopb = Button(root, text="Stop", command=stoptime)
stopb.pack()

mainloop()
```

Thanks for any help to this noob ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `start` is a local variable, its value is forgotten when the `starttime` function ends. If you want it to persist you can make it a global variable

```
def starttime():
    global start
    start=datetime.datetime.now()
    print start
```

You should probably at some time read up about why there are local and global variables, and how to avoid using globals too often.

Comment: Thanks James. I kind of already thought that it would be some kind of basic stuff missing. That solved the problem.